# Use Javascript to get current tab url

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a google extension that keeps track of the current and previous tab URLs a user visits. Is there a way to use Javascript to have the chrome extension run in the background check the current tab and return the URL?

My current HTML:

```
   <body>
       <div class="container">
           <h2> Current Tab </h2>
           <div id = "current_url"></div>
           <h2> Previous Tab </h2>
           <div id = "previous_url">  </div>
       </div>

   </body>
```

I tried doing:

```
document.getElementById("current_url").innerHTML = window.location.href;
```

but it does not update when I switch to a new tab.

Comment: Use the History API.

Comment: Sorry I am new to Javascript. Could you please provide an example of how I can use it to get the current tab url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `chrome.tabs.query()`:

```json
"permissions": [ ...
   "tabs"
]
```

This requires that you request access to the `chrome.tabs` in your extension manifest  file:

```js
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true }, tabs => {
    let url = tabs[0].url;
    // Do something with url
});
```

The `lastFocusedWindow` property is used when you want to access the current tab that the user is focused into. You can also use `currentWindow: true` when you want to get the window where your extension's code is currently executing.

**API Reference:** https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-query